# How can I use np.array to speed up calculation instead of looping (with some preconditions)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, performance

I need to use the following code; is it possible to use np.array to do the exact calculation and get the same result faster?

```py
data['daily_change'] = data.groupby('title',group_keys=False)['return'].pct_change()
for title in data['title'].unique(): # Iterate through each title
     
    temp_df = data[data['title'] == title].tail(252) # Select the data for a specific title
    if len(temp_df) < 252:
        print(f"{title} has less than 1 year of data, ignore\n")
        continue

    sections = [temp_df.iloc[i:i+63] for i in range(0, 252, 63)] # Divide the data into 4 sections

    if method1:
        result = sum([(section['return'].iloc[-1] / section['return'].iloc[0]) * weight for section, weight in zip(sections, [0.2]*3 + [0.4])]) # Calculate the weighted return
    else:
        # Calculate the weighted return using the daily changes
        result = sum([(1 + section['daily_change']).prod() * weight for section, weight in zip(sections, [0.2]*3 + [0.4])]) - 1

    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, pd.DataFrame({'title': [title], 'result': [result]})], ignore_index=True)
```

**Additional info:**

Here is the sample data https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehawttyt2rhrkx5/sample.csv?dl=0

Expected result for method1

```
A: 1.00105
B: 1.03288
C: 1.13492
D: 0.966295
E: 1.06095
F: 1.02021
```

Expected result for else condition:

```
A: 0.00526707    
B: 0.0433293
C: 0.14446
D: -0.0129632
E: 0.0601407
F: 0.0263727
```

Short description what I want to do:

1. Compute the daily change in return for each title separately.
2. Take only the most recent 252 data points for each title.
3. Divide the data points for each title into four sections.
4. Run both methods 1 and else calculation for each title.

Method 1 is to take the percentage difference between the last and first data point in each section, multiply it by the respective weight, and total it.

Otherwise, take the daily change product, multiply it by the respective weight, and add it all up.

Comment: Can you share your `data` ? Although you can try to vectorize your calculations. Vectorization means performing operations on entire arrays at once, rather than looping through each element of an array.

Comment: I see a lot of opportunities, but without any data it would be very hard to reproduce. Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example and the desired outcome.

Comment: please provide a small sample dataframe from `data` in order to replicate your task. Provide also a short description of what you are doing

Comment: @Coder Data link shared

Comment: @JarroVGIT Desired outcome provided

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco Description added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a couple assumptions (specifically around `method1` and `df_new`), your current code runs in...

```py
%%timeit
# idk what `method1` is so set it to `True`
method1 = True
# idk what `df_new` is so making an 
# empty dataframe to replicate your code
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

data['daily_change'] = data.groupby('title',group_keys=False)['return'].pct_change()
for title in data['title'].unique(): # Iterate through each title
     
    temp_df = data[data['title'] == title].tail(252) # Select the data for a specific title
    if len(temp_df) < 252:
        print(f"{title} has less than 1 year of data, ignore\n")
        continue

    sections = [temp_df.iloc[i:i+63] for i in range(0, 252, 63)] # Divide the data into 4 sections

    if method1:
        result = sum([(section['return'].iloc[-1] / section['return'].iloc[0]) * weight for section, weight in zip(sections, [0.2]*3 + [0.4])]) # Calculate the weighted return
    else:
        # Calculate the weighted return using the daily changes
        result = sum([(1 + section['daily_change']).prod() * weight for section, weight in zip(sections, [0.2]*3 + [0.4])]) - 1

    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, pd.DataFrame({'title': [title], 'result': [result]})], ignore_index=True)
```

```
7.48 ms ± 532 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

### Some (potentially over-optimized) improvements

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# define a function that can be applied over groups
def func(data: pd.DataFrame, method1: bool = True) -> float:
    # take the last 252 rows
    df = data.tail(252)
    # return nothing if less than 252 rows
    if len(df) < 252:
        return
    # storing `weights` at (4,) array
    weights = np.array([*[0.2]*3, 0.4])
    # idk what method1 is so assuming it's a boolean
    if method1:
        # split `df["return"]` into quarters
        sections = np.array(np.array_split(
            ary=df["return"].to_list(), indices_or_sections=4
        ))
        # shave off a few ms...
        result = np.multiply(
            np.divide(sections[:, -1], sections[:, 0]), weights
        ).sum()
    else:
        # split `df["daily_change"]` into quarters
        sections = np.array(np.array_split(
            ary=df["daily_change"].to_list(), indices_or_sections=4
        ))
        # shave off a few ms...
        result = np.multiply(
            np.add(sections, 1).prod(axis=1), weights
        ).sum() - 1
    
    return result
```

```py
%%timeit
# `method1` is True
data.groupby("title").apply(func, method1=True)
```

```
3.68 ms ± 222 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
# `method1` is False
data.groupby("title").apply(func, method1=False)
```

```
3.87 ms ± 227 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I was able to cut the time down by roughly 50% with the given data.

### Note

If a "title" group doesn't have enough rows the function will return nothing. The results may look like this:

```py
dfc = data.sample(1_500, random_state=0)

# these numbers will not be correct due to sampling
print(dfc.groupby("title").apply(func))
```

```
title
A         NaN
B         NaN
C         NaN
D         NaN
E    1.282753
F    0.928689
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, more than 50%, +30 sec vs 2 sec lol